# How to directly subscribe a signal of signal without flattenMap when using ReactiveCocoa?

Tags: objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I have a method that returns a signal of signal and I have to use `flattenMap` to extract the value wrapped in the signal. After that only can I use subscribeNext:complete: to get the value.

The code looks like the follows:

```
- (RACSignal *)publicSignal {
    return [[self privateSignal] map:^id(NSString *code) {
       return [self chainingSignalUsingCode:code];
    }];
}；


[[[obj publicSignal] flattenMap:^id(id value) {
    return value;
}] subscribeNext:^(NSString *someValue) {
    // extract the value;
} completed:^{
    // something to do..
}];
```

Is there any way to eliminate the `flattenMap` code so that I can directly subscribe to the `publicSignal`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could just do the `flattenMap` inside `publicSignal`...

```
- (RACSignal *)publicSignal {
    return [[[self privateSignal] map:^id(NSString *code) {
       return [self chainingSignalUsingCode:code];
    }] flattenMap:^(id value) {
        return value;
    }];
}

[[obj publicSignal] subscribeNext:^(NSString *someValue) {
    // extract the value;
} completed:^{
    // something to do..
}];
```

But then why are we `map`ping and then immediately `flattenMap`ping? We can just say:

```
- (RACSignal *)publicSignal {
    return [[self privateSignal] flattenMap:^(NSString *code) {
       return [self chainingSignalUsingCode:code];
    }];
}

[[obj publicSignal] subscribeNext: ...
```

To get the same effect.

Bear in mind that `flattenMap` isn't really "extracting the value in the signal." It's extracting *all* the values from *all* the signals. When `privateSignal` sends new signals, `publicSignal` is going to next for *every* value that *every* signal sends -- it's basically going to remember all past signals that `privateSignal` sends and forward all of their nexts through. If this is what you want, then great, it works. But if you only want to "unwrap" the latest signal, use `switchToLatest` instead of `flattenMap`.

If you don't want to modify `publicSignal`, and you want it to be a signal of signals, you can use the simpler `flatten` method and subscribe to that:

```
[[[obj publicSignal] flatten] subscribeNext: ...
```

Since `flattenMap` without doing anything is equivalent to `flatten` (in fact `flatten` is implemented as a `flattenMap` that just returns its value). Or, if you only want to subscribe to nexts from the latest signal it sends:

```
[[[obj publicSignal] switchToLatest] subscribeNext: ...
```

But as long as it's a signal of signals, you need to do some operation to "unwrap" it. there's no helper `flattenAndThenSubscribe` method -- which is good. You can get the effect you want through composition of simple primitives.

Comment: So If I want to 'unwrap' the latest signal, instead of using `flattenMap` in the implementation of `publicSignal`, I should still keep `map` in `publicSignal` and send `switchToLatest` to `publicSignal`, is that right?

Comment: @NoahBlues I think it is, but there's only one way to find out! Test it and make sure it does what you're expecting with your signals.

Comment: I've tested them, both worked. `switchToLatest` must be sent to a `RACDynamicSignal`, and a signal of signal is of type `RACDynamicSignal`. So `switchToLatest` can not be sent to a signal that followed by `flattenMap`.